# How to always have the latest working copy of a git repo?

Tags: git

Is there a way to set up a repository to "mirror" the remote so that I always have the latest working copy?

I guess I can simply clone it and pull on occasion (without ever pushing), but ideally I want each push to the remote to cause the "mirror" to update.

The reason for this is that I want to have the latest working copy so that I can easily test the current state of the repo.

I mostly care about only one branch, but if I have the all, that's even better.

Comment: google 'git post receive hook'

Comment: So you are suggesting calling rsync in a post receive hook?

Comment: @ventsyv Probably easier to keep a repo on the mirror server and have the server hook on the remote server invoke `git pull` on the mirror server. But afaik rsync would work too. Here is a tutorial I found: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks

Comment: you can just `git push` to another repo from the post receive hook

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in "push notification", i.e., no built in method by which you can declare repository R<sub>M</sub> on machine *M* (the "master copy" machine) to be "the master", with repository R<sub>S</sub> on machine *S* (the "slave") mirroring it.  One typical solution is just to have machine *S* poll *M* regularly (perhaps every 5 minutes) by running `git remote update` on it.  If you set up *S* to refuse pushes, and with its `fetch` line for *M* set to `+refs/*:refs/*`, it will be a true mirror; and if you fetch out of a cron entry every 5 minutes, it will be at most 5 minutes out of date.

At a previous job, we were experimenting with using a lightweight(ish) protocol (ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ, or whatever) on the master machine, sending "push notices" to the (multiple) slaves, so that we could cut the polling interval way down (possibly all the way to zero although there are some bootstrapping issues after a slave has been down or network-partitioned for a while).

Comment: Polling isn't a bad solution, but I feel a solution involving hooks might be more efficient, because as far as I know it would prevent the need for polling every 5 minutes.

Comment: Yes, hence the idea of having push-notices.  I was going to write a post-receive hook to do this, but never got to it before I changed jobs anyway.  (It was more complex than it looks as we had dozens of repositories and multiple slave sites.)